# Qt ugly font on Hyper-V machine

Tags: windows, qt, qt5, hyper-v

I encountered some strange behavior of my first Qt 5.3 application:
It looks OK on a real OS, but text in all widgets looks ugly on virtual Hyper-V machine (Windows 7).
When I enlarged the screenshot, I saw that the text is ether not antialiased at all (`QToolbar`) or antialiased the strange way (other widgets)

I tried:

```
QFont f = app->font();
f.setStyleStrategy(QFont::PreferAntialias);
app->setFont(f);
```

The font became better looking, but it no longer looked native on all machines (physical and virtual).

And the strangest thing:

```
app->setFont(app->font());
```

Produces the same effect.

Comment: Maybe it is not the same fonts by default. What is `f->family()` on each platform?

Comment: "MS Shell Dlg 2" on all platforms

Comment: Can you open a Microsoft office app (word, excel, etc..), and look if `MS Sans Serif` is in the font list?

Comment: I have just discovered that the problem is only on virtual Hyper-V machine where I do testing for different OS. On physical Win 7 machines everything is OK! I changed my original post accordingly.

Comment: Do you access them via RDP? There are options in RDP to enhance bandwidth usage AFAIK one of them was to disable anti-aliased font rendering.

Comment: No, I access them directly with Hyper-V Manager. With RDP everything is OK.

Comment: I guess the problem may be in Hyper-V video driver, but I wonder why it affects only my Qt App and does not affect other programs. Does Qt uses some unique API to draw text?